# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address 0x1)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

So Yeah. I ran my application (an RSS reader) and I received this error. It points to this line: `0x10e0098:  movl   (%eax), %edx` and the code in my MainViewController.m is

```
UIViewController *WebViewController =
 [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController.h" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

the nib name does not have the .h extension (that is the header file). Try this:

```
UIViewController *WebViewController =
 [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
```

assuming the filename of your nib is WebViewController.xib.

Comment: But have you created a Xib? And what's its name?

Comment: I have. It's WebViewController.xib. But I still get the error

Comment: Profile the app with NSZombie enabled and it should give you more information about what is going wrong.